# How can i start another exe after all files re verified on the xml list? c#

Tags: c#, xml

i want to start another exe when verify all the files up to date which is stated on the update xml file. On my code, when check a file exe starts but it starts when every file check. For example i have 5 files on the xml it starts 5 times. i want to start the exe if only all files are up to date and only one time.

```
foreach (XmlNode dosya in dosyalar.SelectNodes("dosya"))
        {
            string dosyaadi = dosya.SelectSingleNode("dosyaadi").InnerText;
            if (File.Exists(yerelklasor + "/" + dosyaadi)==false)
            {
                WebClient indir = new WebClient();
                Uri yol = new Uri(dosya.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
                indir.DownloadFileAsync(yol, (yerelklasor + "/" + dosyaadi));
                indir.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(indir_indirmetamamlandi);
                indir.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(indir_indirmedurumu);
            }
        }

            foreach (XmlNode dosya in dosyalar.SelectNodes("dosya"))
        {
            string dosyaadi = dosya.SelectSingleNode("dosyaadi").InnerText;


            SifreCevir = sifreleme.MD5sifrele(yerelklasor + "/" + dosyaadi);
            if(SifreCevir != (dosya.SelectSingleNode("md5").InnerText))
            {

                label1.Text = "Güncellenen dosya: " + dosyaadi;
                WebClient indir = new WebClient();
                Uri yol = new Uri(dosya.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
                indir.DownloadFileAsync(yol, (yerelklasor + "/" + dosyaadi));
                indir.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(indir_indirmetamamlandi);
                indir.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(indir_indirmedurumu);
            }



            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process baslat = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                baslat.StartInfo.FileName = oyunexe;
                baslat.Start();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exe is starting 5 times because the `else` statement that launches it is in the final `foreach` loop. Move it outside the loop and it it should be fine.

```
foreach (XmlNode dosya in dosyalar.SelectNodes("dosya"))
    {
        string dosyaadi = dosya.SelectSingleNode("dosyaadi").InnerText;
        if (File.Exists(yerelklasor + "/" + dosyaadi)==false)
        {
            WebClient indir = new WebClient();
            Uri yol = new Uri(dosya.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
            indir.DownloadFileAsync(yol, (yerelklasor + "/" + dosyaadi));
            indir.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(indir_indirmetamamlandi);
            indir.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(indir_indirmedurumu);
        }
    }

    foreach (XmlNode dosya in dosyalar.SelectNodes("dosya"))
    {
        string dosyaadi = dosya.SelectSingleNode("dosyaadi").InnerText;


        SifreCevir = sifreleme.MD5sifrele(yerelklasor + "/" + dosyaadi);
        if(SifreCevir != (dosya.SelectSingleNode("md5").InnerText))
        {

            label1.Text = "Güncellenen dosya: " + dosyaadi;
            WebClient indir = new WebClient();
            Uri yol = new Uri(dosya.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText);
            indir.DownloadFileAsync(yol, (yerelklasor + "/" + dosyaadi));
            indir.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(indir_indirmetamamlandi);
            indir.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(indir_indirmedurumu);
        }
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Process baslat = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    baslat.StartInfo.FileName = oyunexe;
    baslat.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you, and some times if there is no file exe is giving error. I think checking file avaiblity code is wrong too :) @user783836